# strange instruction call in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I don't have a syscall code in my MIPS instruction, however in the simulator I can see the following:

[image]

I don't have any of the following code line in my .s

```
li $v0 10
syscall
```

Why is that? It's bothering me as it gives me a bad address in the syscall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a syscall used by the simulator to exit from the program (it gives control  back to operating system), you can get a summary of available syscall of *Spim* here: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20070704070408/http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~eduardob/disciplinas/arqi/mips/syscall_codes.html).

The simulator adds a bootstrap at the beginning and an end section at the end of your program. Since you specify which `syscall` to execute by loading the corresponding value in register `$v0` that's what it actually does: set the syscall to be the `exit` one and the call it with `syscall`.